Minimal dominating sets in thin hypergraphs
Let $H=(V,E)$ be a hypergraph. We say that $H$ is thin if for every $v\in V$ the set $E_v=\{e\in E:v\in e\}$ is finite.
A subset $D\subseteq V$ is dominating if
$\bigcup \{e\in E:e\cap D \neq \emptyset\} = V$.
Question. Does every thin hypergraph $H=(V,E)$ with $\bigcup E = V$ have a minimal dominating set $D_0\subseteq V$? ($D_0\subseteq V$ is minimal dominating if for all $d\in D_0$ the set $D_0\setminus \{d\}$ is no longer dominating.)

In the definition of a do inating set, should the union be really $V$ but not $E$?

I don't think so, @IlyaBogdanov, because we take the union over some edges $e\in E$, and this union gives a subset of $V$ -> which we require to equal $V$. Does that make sense?

The answer seems to be yes.
Any maximal independent(=no two its vertices share an edge) set is a minimal dominating set. It exists by Zorn’s lemma.
The condition on finite degrees is not used…
======================
This is a previous (wrong) answer, as I misread the definition of a dominating set.
Choose $V=\{1,2,\dots\}$ and let the edges be $e_i=\{i,i+1,\dots\}$. The dominating sets are precisely infinite ones.

Isn't that dominated by any singleton, because all singletons have non-empty intersection with $e_1 = V$?

@PeterTaylor you need all edges to be pierced by the dominating set. So the dominating set should contain arbitrarily large numbers…

Are you using a different definition of dominating? I don't see how $\bigcup {e\in E:e\cap D \neq \emptyset} = V$ requires ${e\in E:e\cap D \neq \emptyset} = E$ as you claim.

Eh… Seems that I really misread the question, but then this is really not the usual definition…

It seems to be equivalent to e.g. definition 1.2 of Acharya, B. D. (2007). Domination in hypergraphs. AKCE International Journal of Graphs and Combinatorics, 4(2), 117-126.

Now it seems to be an answer to the question as asked.
